# Rails 4.2 Active Record Serializer JSON format issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer on rails that has another nested serializer inside like this

```
class FeedSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  has_one :user

  def user
    if object.anonymous
        nil
    else
        UserFeedSerializer.new(object.user)
    end
  end
end
```

I expected the JSON response to be like

```
{
    "feed": {
        "id": 10
        "user": {
            "id": 10
        }
    }
}
```

But instead it's doing this:

```
{
    "feed": {
        "id": 10
        "user": {
            "user_feed": {
                "id": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it including an extra nest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing serializer for user relation, not the User instance itself. Try disabling root attribute wrapping by placeing `root false` at the top of UserFeedSerializer.

Comment: awesome thanks that was it! Do you know if you can turn this on/off if I wanted to use `UserFeedSerializer` as a root for a different feed instead of just adding `self.root = false` in the class file?

Comment: Subclass it specially for this case. :)